# Could not find or load main class org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule - Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, datasource, wildfly, wildfly-10

I wanted to encrypt the password in the configuration of connections to the database. I was stuck at the stage of generating an encrypted password

I wrote the script bat, the content of which is:

```
java -cp c:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logging\main\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:c:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar:c:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final.jar:c:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-infinispan-4.9.4.Final.jar org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule password
```

Unfortunately, when you start this script i getting error:

```
C:\>test.bat

C:\>java -cp c:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layer
s\base\org\jboss\logging\main\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:c:\ADS\JPK\wildfly_1
0_jpk\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketb
ox-4.9.4.Final.jar:c:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system
\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final.jar:c:\ADS\JPK\wil
dfly_10_jpk\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\p
icketbox-infinispan-4.9.4.Final.jar org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIden
tityLoginModule password
Error: Could not find or load main class org.picketbox.datasource.security.Secur
eIdentityLoginModule

C:\>
```

I decompiled class SecureIdentityLoginModule and I see that you are there main method ...
I used the server to Wildfly 10.0.0 Final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong path separator. On Windows it's a semicolon `;`. You're using the UNIX/Linux path separator `:`.

It should be:

```
java -cp C:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logging\main\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-4.9.4.Final.jar;C:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final.jar;C:\servers\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-infinispan-4.9.4.Final.jar org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule password
```